# Get duplicate and unique data between two multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

There's a lot of questions out there that deals between arrays and multi-dimensional arrays but only one so how about two then? Let's say this is the data:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [BRANCHCODE] => 2
        [BRANCH] => BRANCH 1
        [AGREEID] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [BRANCHCODE] => 2
        [BRANCH] => BRANCH 2
        [AGREEID] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [BRANCHCODE] => 2
        [BRANCH] => BRANCH 3
        [AGREEID] => 3
    )
)

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [BRANCHCODE] => 2
        [BRANCH] => BRANCH 4
        [AGREEID] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [BRANCHCODE] => 2
        [BRANCH] => BRANCH 5
        [AGREEID] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [BRANCHCODE] => 2
        [BRANCH] => BRANCH 6
        [AGREEID] => 5
    )
)
```

I managed to get the duplicated data but I can't get the unique data. Here's the php code on how I got the duplicates and also the count of the duplicated data.

In here I loop through both of the two arrays the first one is the array of the uploaded data and the next loop is the database results. I compared the two arrays if the AGREEID in the uploaded data has duplicate in the database. If the AGREEID in the uploaded data is unique I will insert it in the database.

```
foreach ($result as $key=>$upload_data) {
        $agreeid_upload = $result[$key]['AGREEID'];
        $data = $result[$key];
        $another_data = $result[$key];

        foreach ($reports as $dbase_data) {
            $agreeid = $dbase_data->AGREEID;
            if($agreeid_upload == $agreeid){ /// record has duplicate in the database
                $count_duplicates = $count_duplicates + 1;
                $duplicates[$key] = $data;
            }else{
                ///here i want to store into another array the unique data.. 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the intent is for the agree id to be a primary key then define it as one on your table then just insert all and catch the duplicate key exceptions. Your successful attempts will be your uniques and your exceptions will be your dups.

Answer (score 1):

The method used would work, but is going to be inefficient with a large amount of data because it will do a lot of extra looping.

```
$dbAgreeeData = array();
$duplicates = array();
$unique = array();
foreach ($reports as $dbase_data) {
    $dbAgreeeData[$db_dbase_data->AGREEID] = $dbase_data;
}

foreach ($result as $key=>$upload_data) {
    $agreeId = $upload_data['AGREEID'];
    if (isset($dbAgreeeData[$agreeId)){
        $duplicates[$agreeId] = $upload_data;
    }
    else {
        $unique[$agreeId] = $upload_data;
    }
}
$numDuplicate = count($duplicates);
$numUnique = count($unique);
```

Or

```
$dbAgreeeData = array();
$uploadData= array();

foreach ($reports as $dbase_data) {
    $dbAgreeeData[$db_dbase_data->AGREEID] = $dbase_data;
}
foreach ($result as $key=>$upload_data) {
    $uploadData[$upload_data['AGREEID']] = $upload_data;
}

$duplicates = array_intersect_key($dbAgreeData, $uploadData;
$unique = array($dbAgreeData, $uploadData);
$numDuplicate = count($duplicates);
$numUnique = count($unique);
```

Comment: my database holds thousands of records to be compared

Comment: Yeah, so it is faster to loop once to make array indexed by all the ids, and then loop the uploaded data once to check for duplicate/unique, otherwise it would loop through whole db for each element  in uploaded array.  Doing isset() is really fast for comparing this sort of thing, I made a script a while ago that compared hundreds of thousands of skus vs the database each night and it was fairly quick.

Comment: that was pretty neat.. is there any faster way or simpler way rather than that?

Comment: You can use some built in array functionality, such as 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php
if you were to make an array of upload information keyed by agree id first.  Also can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php to find differences between arrays based on key.